# Sidebar hide/show button that follows cursor mouse?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a sidebar on HTML that has a button that opens and closes that sidebar.. something like this:
(the bar is a div)

```
    | |open> <--- this is the button
    | |
    | |
    | |
    | |

    on click:
    - Menu 1 | |close> 
    - Menu 2 | |
    - Menu 3 | |
    - Menu 4 | |
```

What i whant is that if i move the mouse over the bar, the open/close button moves with it but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: could you post some of your source code or more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you could provide some of your source html and css i could get you a more specific answer,  but using CSS and JQUERY similar to my example below should give you the effect you are looking for...

the process is listening to the mousemove event with jquery and storing the mouse's Y position in a js variable.  then we are adjusting the '.button's CSS to match that value.

specifically this method is going to rely on your button having an absolute position with a value declared for TOP.

HTML

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

JS

```
var posY;

$(document).mousemove( function(e) { 
   posY = e.pageY;
    $('.button').css({'top': posY});
});
```

CSS

```
.button {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    /* ... */
}
```

[you can find it all together here in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFyRk/) with the button moving vertically to follow the mouse